# List off-diagonal values from levenshtein distance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, levenshtein-distance

Using the following data, how can I create a DataFrame with the column 'id' as an index and a second column containing a list of off-diagonal values from a Levenshtein distance matrix for the list of strings corresponding to each id?

```
d = {'id':[1,1,1,2,2],'string':['roundys','roundys','ppg','brewers','cubs']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The goal is to generate a DataFrame that looks something like

```
df_diag = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'diag_val':['0.0,7.0,7.0','6.0']})
```

I have built some rough pieces that work with a single list but have not been able to iterate by 'id' across multiple lists. Am using pandas as 'pd', numpy as 'np' and distance from Levenshtein as 'dist'

**Step 1 Create a Test List**

```
aTest = ['roundys','roundys','ppg']
```

**Step 2 Create Function that Returns Edit Distance Matrix from aTest**

```
def editDistance(list_o_strings):
    matrix = np.zeros(shape = (len(list_o_strings),len(list_o_strings)))

    for i in range(len(list_o_strings)):
        for j in range(i, len(list_o_strings)):
            matrix[i][j] = dist(list_o_strings[i],list_o_strings[j])
    for i in range(0, len(list_o_strings)):
        for j in range(0,len(list_o_strings)):
            if i == j:
                matrix[i][j] = 0
            elif i > j:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i]
    return matrix
```

**Step 3 Create Function that Returns Off-diagonal Edit Distance Terms**

```
def selectElements(matrix):
    ws = []
    for i in range(0, matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, matrix.shape[1]):
            if i <> j and i>j:
                ws.append(matrix[i,j])
    return ws
```

**Step 4 Test the Example List**

```
testDistance = editDistance(aTest)
testOffDiag = selectElements(testDistance)
```

My next step is to iterate the functions over the unique id values within the dataset.  I created a new data frame of id paired to a list of strings with

```
df1 = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

My attempts to have the functions loop through the id terms have failed miserably, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Levenshtein distance with a `pip` install

```
pip install python-Levenshtein
```

Then you can do something like this

```
from Levenshtein import distance
from itertools import combinations

def lm(a):
  return [distance(*b) for b in combinations(a, 2)]

df.groupby('id').string.apply(lm).reset_index(name='diag_val')

   id   diag_val
0   1  [0, 7, 7]
1   2        [6]
```

Or

```
def lm(a):
  return ','.join([str(distance(*b)) for b in combinations(a, 2)])

df.groupby('id').string.apply(lm).reset_index(name='diag_val')

   id diag_val
0   1    0,7,7
1   2        6
```

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has a function, [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) which allows you to compute pairwise distances between elements in an n-dimensional space.  The function also allows for a custom `metric` parameter.

We can feed this function your values, along with a metric function calculated using the `python-Levenshtein` library.

***Setup***

```
from Levenshtein import distance
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
```

Using `pdist` with a custom metric:

```
def lm(x):
    return pdist(x.values.reshape(-1, 1), lambda x,y: distance(x[0],y[0]))

res = pd.DataFrame(
    [(i, lm(g)) for i, g in df.groupby('id').string],
    columns=['id', 'diag_val']
)
```

```
   id         diag_val
0   1  [0.0, 7.0, 7.0]
1   2            [6.0]
```

Comment: I am using the same method for calculating levenshtein distance, but I am wondering if there is some way to speed it up, using multiprocessing? It is to slow and it use only one core.